# Generating events from SQL server

Tags: sql-server, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am looking for a best practice or example of how I might be able to generate events for all update events on a given SQL Server 2008 R2 db. To be more descriptive, I am working on a POC where I would essentially publish update events to a queue (RabbitMq in my case) that could then be consumed by various consumers. This would be the first part of implementing a CQRS query-only data model via event sourcing. By placing on the que anybody could then subscribe to these events for replication into any number of query-only data models. This part is clear and fairly well-defined. the problem I am having is determining the best approach for generating the events out from SQL server. I have been given a few ideas such as monitoring the transaction log and SSIS. However, I'm not entirely sure if these options are adviseable or even feasible.

Does anybody have any experience with this sort of thing or have any notions on how to go about such an adventure? any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to store things into SQL Server?

Comment: You can enable Change Data Capture (CDC) per table to create a "shadow table" that automatically stores records when an insert, update or delete statement is executed against the source table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot monitor the log because, even *if* you would be able to understand it, you have the problem of the log being recycled *before* you had a chance to read it. Unless the log is somehow marked not to be truncated it will reused. For instance when transactional replication is enabled the log be pinned until is read by the replication agent and only *then* truncated.

SSIS is a very broad concept and saying that 'using SSIS to detect changes' is akin to saying 'I'll use a programing language to solve my problem'. The details is *how* would you use SSIS? There is no way, with or without SSIS, to reliably detect data changes on an arbitrary schema. Even data models specifically designed to allow for detecting changes have issues, specially at detecting deletes.

However there are viable alternatives. You can deploy [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx) and delegate to the engine itself to track the changes. Consuming these detected changes and publishing them to consumers (via RabbitMQ if that's your fancy) *is* a something SSIS would be good at. But you have to understand that SSIS does not fare well to continuos, real-time tasks. It is designed to run periodically on batches, so your change notification consumers will be notified in spikes, with long delays (minutes), when the SSIS jobs run.

For a real-time approach a better solution is [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx). One possibility is to [`SEND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) Service Broker messages from triggers, but I would not recommend it. A better design is to have the application itself publish the changes by `SEND`-ing the message explicitly, when it does the data modification. With SQL Server 2012 is possible to [multicast Service Broker messages](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/20/how-to-multicast-messages-with-sql-server-service-broker/) to other SQL Server consumers (including SQL Server Express). SSB message delivery is fully transactional (no message gets sent if transaction rolls back) and does not require two-phase-commit with a message store resource manager. But to broadcast via RabbitMQ you would need to bridge the communication, ie. [`RECEIVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186963.aspx) the SSB messages and transform them into RabbitMQ notifications.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. I don't believe SSIS is the solution for me as I need more real-time data. (not 100% real-time but close). Having the application making the change publish would be ideal. However, we have many different entry points currently, in different languages and different levels of support. Changing all of these may be considered too onerous. I'm going to investigate Change Data Capture first as it seems to most closely fit what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Incidentally, NServiceBus supports queueing using both SQL Server (docs.particular.net/transports/sql) and RabbitMQ (docs.particular.net/transports/rabbitmq) and running a bridge between the two – docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge. The only "special" work this would require in SQL Server would be to write some code "triggers?" which react to database events (create, update, delete) and write the appropriate events into the NServiceBus message table, as if they were coming from any other non-NServiceBus source – https://docs.particular.net/transports/sql/native-integration